# Shift Key Won't Capitalize Until I Leave it First

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, shift

I just re-installed Windows on my Asus laptop and the Shift key is behaving a bit weirdly. When I press Shift and a letter like A, the letter doesn't appear. It only appears when I leave shift first. Otherwise nothing appears.

This is only happening with some keys : QADFJKL:"XCVM<>?

I thought this was because the Chinese keyboard was installed, so I removed all the other keyboards except US English.

But that doesn't help. I have to remember to leave off the shift key first.

I guess this is because of some app or setting in Windows 7.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why only some letters, but it makes me think of ["Sticky Keys" or "Toggle Keys"](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/windows7/default.aspx) may be turned on.